# Xamarin Build Process

Tags: c#, .net, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin-studio

I'm learning Xamarin. We have two ways to share our codes across platform, i.e. [Shared Project and Portable Class Libraries](http://developer.xamarin.com/guides/cross-platform/application_fundamentals/building_cross_platform_applications/sharing_code_options/).

I want to know what is happening, in detail, when I click on the "Play" button in Xamarin Studio. In particular, I'm interested in the build process for Xamarin. I have another related question: Is there a way to modified the build process?

Comment: With a PCL you get a separate dll, with a shared project, it is compiled into each platform separately, kind of like the old dynamic and static linking of libraries in C++, where with the latter one the code was linked into the resulting binary, whereas else it would just contain the references into the separate .dll, which would be now the PCL).

Answer (score 1):

I can not tell you what happens exactly within the build process but I can tell you that both types of sharing code have there advantages as well as down sides. And I personally prefer SharedProjects over Portable Class Libraries (PCLs).

The reason for this is that PCLs provide the minimal common denominator of the platform that your PCL profile support. Which can be sometimes annoying. A PCL is simplified nothing else as an assembly you reference in you project.

A SharedProject on the other side will be compiled into your project to a monolith. You can use compiler switches and such. Simplified it is a better way of linking files between different projects.

Xamarin has a good guide about [Code sharing options](http://developer.xamarin.com/guides/cross-platform/application_fundamentals/building_cross_platform_applications/sharing_code_options/) you should read through.

Comment: +1 for shared projects. Should still try to use dependency injection/moving platform specific stuff into respective projects, but sometimes it is just too big of a hassle, especially for quick tests and workarounds (e. g. UI related or related to internals).